# sql transactions in a booking system and preventing booking errors in concurrency

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, concurrency, transactions

I'm building a class booking system in C# against SQL Server (latest version) db.

I need to count the number of available spaces before reserving the booking. I need to be sure that the count does not change in the time it takes for the booking to be reserved.

My concern is that another user will reserve a booking in the space between counting remaining spaces and creating the reservation. I have assumed that if the count and the create reservation are within a transaction that this should force the next user to wait until the first ts has completed. Does this seem a reasonable approach? Is it flawed? I am finding it hard to work out what happens in this instance when two requests hit the DB at the same time. SQL Server will be using the default isolation level of READ COMMITTED.

I have confirmed by testing that if there is an error and transaction.Complete() is not called then the reservation insert is rolled back.

Here is some simplified outline code:

```
       using var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);
            
       const string sql = "; EXEC [dbo].[sp_CountRemainingPlaces] @Class, @School";
       RemainingSpaces = _repository.ExecuteScalar<int>(sql, new { BookingForm.Class, BookingForm.School });

       if (RemainingSpaces == 0)
       {
       // send the user to the waiting list page with all the details
       }

       // if the user has requested more spaces than remain we must send them back with an error
       if(SpacesRequiredByUser > RemainingSpaces) 
       {
               
       }

       // create the booking reservation
       BookingForm.Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
       await _repository.InsertAsync(BookingForm);
         
       transaction.Complete();   // complete the transaction if no error
```

I could put both the count and the reservation insert into a proc which would likely make it more efficient. The transaction would then be in the proc. A return flag would tell the code  what happened.

I'm using .Net 6 with [Dapper.Database](https://github.com/dallasbeek/Dapper.Database).

Update: Here is the count proc and function used.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[sp_CountRemainingPlaces]
    @Class uniqueidentifier, 
    @School uniqueidentifier

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @PlacesBooked int
declare @PlacesRemaining int
declare @PlacesAvailableToPublicAtSchool int

set @PlacesAvailableToPublicAtSchool = (select MaxNumberOfCourseAttendees - MaxNumberOfCourseAttendeesSchool from dbo.School where Guid=@School)
set @PlacesBooked = (select dbo.fn_CountAllReservedBookings(@Class))

if(@PlacesAvailableToPublicAtSchool = 0)
    BEGIN
        select 0 as PlacesRemaining
    END
else
    BEGIN
        set @PlacesRemaining = @PlacesAvailableToPublicAtSchool - @PlacesBooked
        select isnull(@PlacesRemaining, 0) as PlacesRemaining
    END

END
GO

/* A reseverd booking is 

Not abandoned and Not manually released

 -- paid and pending bookings are reserved
 -- paid bookings that were later released manually are not reserved

*/

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_CountAllReservedBookings
(
    @Class uniqueidentifier
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @ResultVar int

SELECT @ResultVar = sum(ChildCount) from Booking
    where Class=@Class 
        and UserAbandonedPaymentYN = 0
        and ManuallyReleasedYN = 0
        and BookingType='PUBLIC'

RETURN ISnull(@ResultVar, 0)

END
GO
```

Comment: You haven't show your counting SQL query, but it would need an `UPDLOCK` hint for it to be effective.

Comment: I'm not sure if or why I'd need a UPDLOCK because the users are not editing the same data. They are getting a sum of a col for a given ID in a select before inserting their own row.

Comment: I'd recommend an optimistic approach instead; check the spaces when you make the booking. If they aren't available it's either tough luck, or maybe you can ask the user for a list of valid dates up front and then you can try the next one that works for them

Comment: So you can block that `SUM` from changing by using `UPDLOCK` on that table. I'm assuming the insert would change that sum, so you need to lock it

Comment: Ok, thanks @Charlieface. Yes an insert will change the SUM.  I am under the impression that transactions are isolated from eachother. So one has to finish before the next can complete. But I guess it's not as simple as that. I'll read up on UPDLOCk, ta.

Comment: I am not sure that UPDLOCK will work. It won't prevent the SUM from changing before the insert. From another SO post:  "Then you should use one of the higher transaction isolation levels. REPEATABLE READ will prevent the data you read from being modified. SERIALIZABLE will prevent the data you read from being modified and new data from being inserted. Using transaction isolation levels is the right approach, as opposed to using query hints. Kendra Little has a nice poster explaining the isolation levels."

Comment: Yes, you could use `SERIALIZABLE`, at the cost of concurency and possibly deadlocks, because it will apply to all tables. You could use it as a hint on just that one table. You're right that `UPDLOCK` won't help, because it doesn't block inserts, only updates or deletes

Comment: Thanks, I'll explore that possibility.

Comment: I always pair both hints like in `FROM MyTable t WITH(UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)` and depend on `read committed snapshot isolation` for maximum performance on non-updating readers (reports).

Answer (score 1):

The kind comments from @Charlieface and @wqw helped me to come up with what I believe is a workable solution.

I worked through [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6368/sql-server-readcommittedsnapshot-database-option-and-read-commited-transaction-isolation-level/) to get an understanding. Then I decided to try out setting the database to READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT_ON. In SQL Server.

```
-- lists db options with isolation level at the bottom
dbcc useroptions
-- set the isolation level
ALTER DATABASE BookingDB SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

Then in the function that counts the number of remaining bookings I added these hints:

```
SELECT @ResultVar = sum(ChildCount) from Booking t WITH(UPDLOCK, 
SERIALIZABLE)
```

I realised that since there is a batch job that expires reserved bookings that are not paid after 20 minutes there was an update happening on some booking rows from time to time. So I decided to go with UPDLOCK and test.

I then created two test scripts the first one having a delay. I then ran the first and then the second immediately after. I need to do a lot more testing but I got predictable results. If the first script took the last booking the second script returned the correct number of remaining spaces of zero. I will need to do a lot more testing to be sure but I think this will work.

First script:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

declare @PlacesRemaining int
declare @PlacesAtSchool int = 12;
declare @PlacesRequested int = 1

set @PlacesRemaining = @PlacesAtSchool - (select 
dbo.fn_CountAllReservedBookings('4819B266-F493-489C-B994-E8D4CD437A3E'))
select @PlacesRemaining as PlacesRemainingBefore

if @PlacesRemaining >= @PlacesRequested
    begin
        INSERT INTO dbo.Booking (Guid,Class,ParentCarerFirstName,ParentCarerLastName,           ParentCarerEmail,ParentCarerPhone,Course,CourseYear,CourseTerm,ClassType,[Day],NumberOfWeeks,ChildCount,School,BookingDate,PaidYN,UserAbandonedPaymentYN,ManuallyReleasedYN,ClassPriceTotal,TotalGBP,    RecipeFolderPrice,RecipeFolderCount,RecipeFolderTotal,AllowMedicalCareYN,AllowPhotoUseYN,BookingType,Created)
    values(newid(),'4819B266-F493-489C-B994-E8D4CD437A3E','Jane','Doe','bunter@bunt.com','121212121','1E434F24-BA22-4FC1-9F01-C9103EE4073F',2022,'Spring','After School',
        'Monday','12',@PlacesRequested,'C7911620-5DFA-4084-991D-17EACE391620', getdate(),0,0,0,6.95,165.00,5.50,1,5.50,1,1,'PUBLIC',getdate())

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:09'
end
else
BEGIN
    select sum(childCount) as TotalSpacesReserved from Booking 
    select 'There are not enough spaces left!'
END

COMMIT
```

Second Script:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

declare @PlacesRemaining int
declare @PlacesAtSchool int = 12;
declare @PlacesRequested int = 1

set @PlacesRemaining = @PlacesAtSchool - (select dbo.fn_CountAllReservedBookings('4819B266-F493-489C-B994-E8D4CD437A3E'))

select @PlacesRemaining as PlacesRemainingBefore

if @PlacesRemaining >= @PlacesRequested
    begin
        INSERT INTO dbo.Booking (Guid,Class,ParentCarerFirstName,ParentCarerLastName,
            ParentCarerEmail,ParentCarerPhone,Course,CourseYear,CourseTerm,ClassType,[Day],NumberOfWeeks,
            ChildCount,School,BookingDate,PaidYN,UserAbandonedPaymentYN,ManuallyReleasedYN,ClassPriceTotal,TotalGBP,
            RecipeFolderPrice,RecipeFolderCount,RecipeFolderTotal,AllowMedicalCareYN,AllowPhotoUseYN,BookingType,Created)
        values(newid(),'4819B266-F493-489C-B994-E8D4CD437A3E','Jim','Brown','bunter@bunt.com','121212121','1E434F24-BA22-4FC1-9F01-C9103EE4073F',2022,'Spring','After School',
            'Monday','12',@PlacesRequested,'C7911620-5DFA-4084-991D-17EACE391620', getdate(),0,0,0,6.95,165.00,5.50,1,5.50,1,1,'PUBLIC',getdate())

    end
else
BEGIN
    select sum(childCount) as TotalSpacesReserved from Booking 
    select 'There are not enough spaces left!'
END

COMMIT
```